# Expected value E[7Y] from joint density function

Tags: expected-value

So I'm trying to solve this problem.

Random vector $(X,Y)$ has the joint density function given by $f(x,y)=6 x y^2$, when $0<x<1$, $0<y<1$, and zero otherwise.

What is $E(7Y)$? Answer with at least one decimal place.

I know that $$E[G(X,Y)]=\int\int{g(x,y)f(x,y)}dydx, $$ so I thought that I could do like follows; $E[7Y]=\int\int{7y \cdot 6 x y^2}dydx=\frac{21}{4}$, but it is wrong. Any help and insight would be appreciated!

Comment: It is not wrong.  $\mathsf E(7Y) = \int_0^1\int_0^1 7y\cdot 6xy^2\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x = 21/4$.  Which equals $5.25$ to *at least one decimal*.

Comment: So my solution is right? I guess it's a misprint then. Thank you!